Понимают ли поисковые роботы Yandex микроразметку типа JSON+LD? (SEO)
Сложно понять из комментариев и ответов самого Yandex. Yandex имеет множество статей на данную тематику, но нигде не пишет: сам он воспринимает такую разметку или нет. А если где-то пишет, то скудно и неясно (по крайней мере для меня).
Кто-то знает/может точно ответить, понимают ли роботы Yandex разметку JSON-LD?

Можете сами проверить:
https://www.lamoda.ru/c/355/clothes-zhenskaya-odezhda/
Запрос: "купить одежду в спб женскую"
Там на странице хлебные крошки размечены с помощью json ld. Как видно по выдаче у Яндекса не возникло проблем.


есть впечатление, чтобы кроме хлебных крошек они ничего не считывают

Да конечно понимает, и даже можно проверить её на правильность - в Яндекс.вебмастере
Инструменты->Валидатор микроразметки.
